# How to verify Samsung/Android firmware files - has Samsung published MD5/SHA256 hashes?

Tags: rom-flashing, unbricking, malware, device-firmware, odin

I've soft-bricked my Samsung Galaxy A40FN running Android 9.0 Pie while attempting to disable bloatware via ADB and I'm currently [searching](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/halp-soft-bricked-a40-after-uninstalling-apps-adb.4458303/) for a solution to recover my data and get the system back running. The phone is stuck in a boot loop, but I can get into recovery mode and download mode.

FRP lock is off (no Google account registered on this device) and I didn't activate any encryption on my part.

I didn't try wiping/factory-resetting yet as I need to rescue my data first. One [possible solution](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/help-how-to-flash-without-losing-data.3704358/) for this could be to flash the original firmware using Odin while leaving the `/data` folder untouched:

[image: Source: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/help-how-to-flash-without-losing-data.3704358/]

[image: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/help-how-to-flash-without-losing-data.3704358/]

Question: Does anyone have experience with retaining personal data during a firmware flash and know how to verify the authenticity of the files downloaded from unofficial sources such as [SamFW](https://samfw.com/firmware/SM-A405FN/DBT/A405FNXXU4CVD1)?

I.e. does Samsung publish **MD5 hashes** of official firmware updates and would comparing these hashes/checksums be a reliable method to verify that the files have not been tampered with, considering that firmware files are typically 4-5 GB large?

Comment: Flashing the system image will not help you because you have not uninstalled the apps but only disabled them. Modifications to the system partitions is not possible unless the device is rooted (but if I remember correctly your device is not rooted). So all apps are still present but the config files from the user data partition tells Android they are disabled which causes your device to not boot.

Comment: @Robert So doing *pm uninstall* only removes the apps from the "standard (non-root) user", but they're physically still on the device (I watched the apps disappearing one after the other from the apps list)? Are you suggesting that I need to root the device first in order to get access to the data folder? If yes, is this possible without accidentally wiping everything?

Comment: Rooting does not accidentally wipe the device, it does so by definition. When you unlock the bootloader everything is wiped as this opens a big back door on the encrypted user data.

Comment: @Robert ...and I guess this behavior is hardcoded in some chip and cannot be modified on software level? Or is it?

Comment: Of course not, this would be a disastrous security vulnerability for the Android ecosystem. In the early days of Android 4 there were a few devices which had implemented bootloader unlock factory reset in a defect way, but since that time it is known as a crucial point and thus the manufacturer have this functionality on their checklist.

Comment: @alecxs Yes, I'm also looking into combination ROMs as suggested, but couldn't make a decision yet on what to try first: Combination ROM or stock firmware using HOME_CSC instead of CSC. The main goal is data recovery

Comment: @alecxs By the way, would you recommend the combination ROM for everyday use, i.e. is there any reason one could or should not use it instead of stock firmware? Does is lack any functionality or is it less secure (maybe due too root privileges)?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I can answer my own question: You can download firmware files directly from Samsung using open-source tools such as [SamLoader](https://www.xda-developers.com/download-samsung-software-updates-samsung-firmware-downloader/).